# How to set focus on <apex:inputText> in ouput panel of visualforce page

Tags: javascript, jquery, visualforce

I am quite new to Visualforce and Apex. I am trying to set focus on the apex inputText field, placed inside an ouputpanel, which will be popped up based on an action function. I tried setting focus using javascript function but none works. Can anyone please help me on this?

Visualforce code:

```
<apex:outputlabel onclick="fnUpdateName('{!ID}','{!Name}');" style="font-weight:normal !important;" > Edit name </apex:outputlabel>
<apex:actionfunction name="actUpdateName" action="{!ShowPopup}" reRender="UpdateName">
                         <apex:param name="Id" value="" assignTo="{!Id}"/>
                         <apex:param name="Name" value="" assignTo="{!Name}"/>                                              
                      </apex:actionfunction>
```

output panel:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="UpdateName">
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!update}"/> 
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="customPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!update}">
<apex:pageBlock >
<div class="panel panel-default">     
<div class="panel-heading">        
<h4><b Style="color:#555">Edit Name</b></h4>
</div> 
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="tblPopUp">  
<tr>    
<td><font style="color:#337ab7">Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
<td> <apex:inputText id="newName" value="{!Name}" styleClass="inputField" onfocus="this.value = this.value;"  /></td> <br/> 
</tr>  
</table>
<br/><br/>
<apex:commandButton value="Update"  action="{!UpdateName}" Render="tblBlock"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel"  action="{!ClosePopup}" />                                                     
</div> 
</div>
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:outputPanel>
```

JS function:

```
function fnUpdateName(ID, Name)
{
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.frmid.DetBlock.tblBlock.popUpBlock.updatePageBlock.newName}').focus();
    actUpdateName(ID, Name);     
}
```

Also,I am getting the below Javascript error, whenever I use setFocus based on component ID, and class name.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Any help is really appreciated..!!

Answer (score 0):

Your *apex:inputText* field is nested thus you should more complete component path specifier as it's described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm).

You should define some Ids on VF components:

1. for *apex:form*
2. for *apex:pageBlock*

And finally full path to the input will look like this:

> '{!$Component.form_id.pageBlock_id.newName}'

outputPanel:

```
<apex:form id="frm">
    <apex:outputPanel id="UpdateName">
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!update}"/> 
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="customPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!update}">
            <apex:pageBlock id="updatePageBlock">
                <div class="panel panel-default">     
                    <div class="panel-heading">        
                        <h4><b Style="color:#555">Edit Name</b></h4>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="tblPopUp">  
                            <tr>    
                                <td><font style="color:#337ab7">Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
                                <td> <apex:inputText id="newName" value="{!Name}" styleClass="inputField" onfocus="this.value = this.value;"  /></td> <br/> 
                            </tr>  
                        </table>
                        <br/><br/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Update"  action="{!UpdateName}" Render="tblBlock"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel"  action="{!ClosePopup}" />                                                     
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </apex:pageBlock> 
        </apex:outputPanel> 
    </apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:form>
```

JS function:

```
function fnUpdateName(ID, Name) {
  document.getElementById('{!$Component.frm.updatePageBlock.newName}').focus();
  actUpdateName(ID, Name);     
}
```

Comment: Thnx for ur suggestion !! Well.. it is not working. Again getting the same error.